# Measurement of high voltage

Tags: adc, high-voltage, voltage-measurement

For research lab work, we use a high-voltage generator to create one pulse with a low intensity (< 4 mA).

The voltage range is variable from 100 V to 3000 V and the FWHM of the pulse is ~1 ms.
The pulse is delivered to different chemical and biological solution with high conductivity value; this implies that the equivalent Rload is low and varying.

[image]

When I delivered the pulse I would like to measure the pulse profile (digitize with an ADC).
So what is the best way to proceed? Perhaps with a simple voltage divider? The HV module is an [XP power F Series](https://www.xppower.com/product/F-Series).

Comment: I'm struggling to combine `"100V to 3000V"`, `"< 4mA"` and `"equivalent Rload is low"` in my head... Either resistance is not actually "low" or the current will be much higher, in which case you can use something like a current transformer.

Comment: Are you planning on some kind of feedback amplifier or switch to control the load voltage? I don't see how you can reliably get a 1ms pulse out of a power supply with 260ms rise time and unknown (and very load-dependent) fall time without additional circuitry. If you have a feedback amplifier then the monitoring more-or-less comes for free. Not that a 3kV amplifier is at all trivial, of course.

Comment: @tobalt your are right. In fact I have the module XPpower F30. And this HV module is interesting for the voltage range [100V ; 3000V]. The specification of F30 the output current is ~4mA but there are no other information. At this time we have testing only the linear behavior of F30 with a voltage divider with several resistor. In my mind the Rload is the resistivity of our biological solution. We doesn't control this parameter, i will measurement this parameter asap. @

Comment: @spehro-pefhany After i have posted i read this rise time value of 260ms. At the start of the project we thought switch  the load voltage with an IGBT. Our specifications are too large but the main element is for us the option to control the pulse value and width with an approximate size of 1ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what is the best way to proceed? Perhaps with a simple voltage divider.

The "best" way depends on a few factors: budget, accuracy, resolution, ...

---

As Andy mentioned in his answer, you can use an HV probe with a scope and fetch the scope data later (e.g. in CSV format) but the bandwidth and the sampling rate should be high enough for an accurate representation. Otherwise, the pulse shape you'll see on the scope may get distorted, which means less accuracy.

I don't know what the pulse is going to look like but if, for example, that 1-ms pulse has a rise time of 10 nanoseconds (the datasheet doesn't mention anything, though) then the probe's bandwidth should be *higher than* 35 MHz to get an accurate representation of the pulse (NOTE: Ignored the scope requirements as even the cheapest ones today have 100 MHz of BW and 1 GSps of sampling rate).

---

The simplest option might look like building a 1000:1 voltage divider and feeding it to a 3V3 ADC: Throw a few 1206-case resistors (their voltage rating is about 200V so 20 of them would be enough), buffer if needed, and done. Layout is very important, always keep your and the circuit's safety in mind (high voltage can "jump", 1 kV/millimetre is a good starting point for clearance).

The accuracy and the speed of the ADC might be a limiting factor here. Depending on the pulse shape and your accuracy requirements, you may need an ADC with a high sampling rate.

Now being a bit pessimistic, if the rise time of the signal is presumably 10 nanoseconds and you want an accurate representation then the sampling rate should be *at least* 70 MHz (Nyquist). If each sample is 8-bit long, you'll need to store 70 kB of data.

Today's popular cheap MCUs go beyond 1 MSps (megasamples per second) with their ADCs. With multi-channel sampling, you can increase the effective sampling rate (e.g. 3-ch interlaced on an STM32F4 will give you 2.4 MSps x 3 = 7.2 MSps). That may give you enough representation.

---

Personally, I'd probe the signal with a scope and fetch the data for further processing.

Comment: i will follow your advice and for first test only probe the signal with a scope and fetch data.

Answer (score 4):

> *what is the best way to proceed? Perhaps with a simple voltage
> divider.*

Undoubtedly this is the only feasible approach and, you have two options: -

- Build yourself a 1000:1 voltage divider with a maximum voltage rating greater than 3 kV
- Buy a 1000:1 oscilloscope probe having a suitable voltage rating and, one you can trust

For either options you can use an oscilloscope or a custom circuit to digitize your waveform. I suspect that the oscilloscope may not be much use if you are monitoring the voltage within a plant process but, you can still use a [10 kV probe](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/oscilloscope-probes/2291019?gb=s) as the main potential divider like this: -

[image]

For the 10 kV probe, it works into a 1 MΩ input impedance that is in parallel with 22 pF. The probe has an adjuster for calibrating waveform shape as per the probe's [instruction sheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/414f/A700000008112466.pdf): -

[image]

> *The HV module is a XP power F Series*

I'm unsure that this device can be used to deliver a pulse to your specification but, if you say it can, who am I to argue?

Comment: If you need more bandwidth, I believe there are some LeCroy 100:1 probes rated for 6000 V with a 400 MHz bandwidth, as well. One of the common problems with high-voltage probes is that they tend to be pretty low-bandwidth.

Comment: @Hearth the one I recommend in my answer has 40 MHz bandwidth and, given that the OP says the pulse is around 1 ms in duration, it will certainly do the job at a fairly modest price of £280. The one you refer to (HVP120) costs around £700 and would need a further stage of attenuation to bring the signal down to the single-volt region of a common ADC input.

Comment: These things are big. A 60 kV, 120 MHz probe (1000:1 into 1M\$\Omega\$) is about 75 mm in diameter with a 120 mm   corona shield and is about 350 mm long. Used to look at a -44 kV pulse of 3.5 \$\mu\$s. The one illustrated by @andyaka is more typical of a probe for a dmm expecting a 10 M\$\Omega\$  load. I see it has a scope bnc but I would be suspicious of it's actual bandwidth

Comment: @DDuck - Although comments can be used to suggest relevant new details (i.e. an improvement suggestion), the reason for your comment isn't clear. For example, the OP's case is a max 3 kV measurement but you talk about a 60 kV probe, Is that relevant here, or intended just as an anecdote? || Then you suggest the answer (which says the probe is intended for a 1 MΩ input impedance) is wrong - yet its datasheet (linked in the answer) says the same. Why do you suggest it's intended for DMMs with 10 MΩ input impedance? || Finally, the datasheet gives its bandwidth. Why are you suspicious? TY